# Select2 Library: change the background color of the selected item

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I am working on a project and to improve the selects I have decided to use the Select2 library.

The project requires a different color palette than the ones used by the library, I have spent a bit of work but I have managed to accommodate my needs with changes in the css. But I have not managed to change the blue color that highlights the selected item when displaying the select.

It would be appreciated if someone has done something similar to guide me. Anyway I leave an image so that you can observe what I mean:

[image]

All the best...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution... need to override the following class:

```
/* Selected option */
.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {  }
```

for example:

```
.select2-results__option[aria-selected=true] {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #9f998d;
}
```

Im sure I try before, but maybe I make a mistake.

Hope this answer can help others... thanks StackOverflow!!!